Migrating from Vite to Rsbuild error: memory allocation of 42 memory allocation of bytes failed
I am using the Rsbuild official website (https://rsbuild.dev/en/guide/migration/vite) to migrate my current project from Vite to Rsbuild. Below is my config file and error message from when I run the project.
rsbuild.config file
import { defineConfig } from '@rsbuild/core';
import { resolve } from 'path'
import {pluginVueJsx} from '@rsbuild/plugin-vue-jsx'
import {pluginVue } from '@rsbuild/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [pluginVue(), pluginVueJsx()],
  html: {
    template: './index.html',
  },

  source: {
    entry: {
      index: './src/main.js',
    },
    alias: {
      '@': resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      '@cps': resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
      'vue-i18n': 'vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.cjs.js',
    },
  }
})

cmd line tool error message
> rsbuild dev

  Rsbuild v1.0.17

  ➜ Network:  http://172.26.96.1:3000/
  ➜ Network:  http://192.168.56.1:3000/
  ➜ Network:  http://192.168.220.1:3000/
  ➜ Network:  http://192.168.14.1:3000/
  ➜ Network:  http://192.168.0.17:3000/
  ➜ Local:    http://localhost:3000/
  ➜ press h + enter to show shortcuts

start   Building...
memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of 42memory allocation of 42memory allocation of memory allocation of  bytes failed
memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of 4242424242424242424242424242424242memory allocation of memory allocation of 424242424242424242424242424242memory allocation of memory allocation of 42memory allocation of memory allocation of  bytes failed
4242memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of memory allocation of
 *  终端进程“C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command npm run dev”已终止，退出代码: 1。 

Could you specify where the problem is and what I should do?

is your machine low on RAM?  what are your system specs, and have you checked how much memory is currently being used vs. available?

Running project with 60% memory, not full
